# Como borrar de forma segura /snap en Linux

Tags: linux

Tras desinstalar el programa Snap en Linux Mint, me ha quedado como carpeta residual /snap.

Es seguro borrarla?

Comment: Si lo has desinstalado , Por que no iba a serlo ? Si esta vacia con mas razon...

Comment: Por si tiene algun enlace solido o simbólico a zonas del sistema

Comment: Mira a ver si esta pregunta de [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112031/can-i-delete-old-snap-folders-which-used-to-be-installed-but-remain-on-system) te sirve. Un saludo.